# Restrict file size upload by type in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, iis-7.5

Is it possible to restrict the allowed file size for uploading in IIS 7.5 by file type?

I want to allow 1MB to images (jpg, png, gif) and 10MB to pdf's and zip's.

Is that possible?

BTW, I'm hosting classic asp sites, and I want to restict it server-side and globally.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may first check the file type, and restrict file size accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The thing is want to do it at the Sever level and globally, not by code and site by site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *Request Filtering* globally/website-level in IIS Server.

Please refer [this article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering). You need to *Edit Feature* for the particular File Extension.